# utf8_decode returns only a part of the encoded string

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have a text in utf-8 and I want to decode it, using `utf8_decode()`
But when I do that I lose a part of the text, `utf8_decode()` decodes the string until it finds a character `â€“`
Any idea to solve this problem ?

Comment: `utf8_decode` converts from UTF-8 to ISO 8859-1. You can loose the characters that are not in ISO 8859-1.

Comment: I know I can lose characters. But you find it normal that half the text after a particular character is lost though it does not contain special chars ?

Comment: With iconv I get this even with `//IGNORE` : `Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string`
Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe iconv can help you

Answer (score 2):

```
â€ = E2 80 = 1110 0010 1000 0000
```

If that's literally what was in your UTF-8 text, then it might not be UTF-8. It would need to be followed by one more octet starting 10 to be valid.

That's because an octet starting 1110 introduces a three octet sequence, with the following octets starting 10, to deliver a total of 16 bytes of 'payload' to give the Unicode code point.

*EDIT: You've provided the next char as 0x93 = 1001 0011 which would be valid. The UTF-8 sequence 0xE28093 = 0010 00 0000 01 0011 = 0x2013 which is an [EN DASH](http://www.decodeunicode.org/en/u+2013/properties). So, it looks like plausible UTF-8 after all!*

Comment: S***... Problem may come from the way data were saved (I try to import from another database which stored utf8 encoded strings in utf8_general_ci tables but not using MySQL `SET NAMES 'utf8'` on connection, when I look via phpmyadmin I see the characters like this : Ã©quipes, all goes well until I found this case with â€“ sequence...)

Comment: To precise, what I have in the text is : `â€“`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `â€“` are not in ISO-8859-1? `utf8_decode` eats only utf8-characters which also exist in ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want something similar to this:

```
$string = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $string);
```

You can read more about iconv in [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php). Depending on your use, IGNORE might be more useful than TRANSLIT.

Comment: Accoding to the comments in the documentation an option of `//TRANSLIT//IGNORE` is also possible, and for some of people solved the problem. I haven't tested it myself, but might be worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that [EdoDodo's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278071/utf8-decode-returns-only-a-part-of-the-encoded-string/4278118#4278118) is not working?

Try to force the browser to handle the output as `iso-8859-1`. To do this, you need an utf8 encoded file with the string in it (you need this, because text editors may use an invisible [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), and the browser may switch to UTF-8 against the defined ISO-8859-2), and an other one with the php code in ansi encoding (I am using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) just to be sure that the encoding is proper - it detects the file's encoding and shows it in the lower right corner, and you can convert between the encodings too).

So create a file in utf-8 encoding called ***utf8.txt*** with just the string:

```
â€“
```

And create an ANSI encoded ***index.php*** file with this content:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> 
<html> 
<head> 
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
</head> 

<body>

<?php
$str = file_get_contents('utf8.txt');

echo "iconv(//IGNORE//TRANSLIT): " . iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE//TRANSLIT", $str) . "<br>\n";
```

For webpages, I strongly recommend to always use UTF-8 encoding, even if it is in English.

Comment: @Serty You can try `iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $str);` to filter out bad chars. See [this article](http://webcollab.sourceforge.net/unicode.html) for further info.

Comment: I just tried this. And it does not remove the problematic characters. And a decoding after cuts the sentence again :/

Comment: @Serty I have successfully replicated the error on an other PHP installation, so edited the answer with the possible solution.

Comment: @Serty just to notice that this is not the one that EdoEdo suggested on his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278071/utf8-decode-returns-only-a-part-of-the-encoded-string/4278118#4278118)'s comment and which you tried before, because that was `//TRANSLIT//IGNORE`, and this one is `//IGNORE//TRANSLIT`, and it works for me this way.

Comment: Yes, it's strange, because my first answer worked on my 5.2.x installation, but not on 5.3.3, and now I tried `//TRANSLIT//IGNORE`, and it is working on 5.3.3 too (and `//IGNORE//TRANSLIT` as well). According to `phpinfo()`, my `libiconv` version is `1.11`, and the `iconv.input_encoding`, `iconv.internal_encoding` and `iconv.output_encoding` are all set to `ISO-8859-1`.

Comment: Funny thing, I was looking for an explanation and found one that involve the iconv C library. I use glibc implementation that does not have //IGNORE...